# AWS Cognito ResendConfirmationCode not emailing code - Node / JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am using the AWS Cognito and trying to allow for users to resend the initial registration confirmation email (aka they register, and lose/forget/wait too long on the email verification link). When they register it sends the email no problem. When I use the code below for users that are registered and confirmed it works.

However, if i use below to try to resend that initial email confirmation link for a user that is not confirmed, it returns the right result but the email is never delivered. Can you please help with the right way to resend the initial email confirmation. Thanks!

```
{
   "CodeDeliveryDetails": { 
      "AttributeName": "email",
      "DeliveryMedium": "email",
      "Destination": "the email address is here"
   }
}
```

```
resendConfirmationCode(userName: string): Promise<any> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            const cognitoUser = this.getUserByUsername(userName);

            cognitoUser.resendConfirmationCode((error: any, result: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
resendConfirmationCode(userName: string): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const cognitoUser = this.getUserByUsername(userName);

        new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider(
         { region: AWS_REGION }
        ).resendConfirmationCode({
            Username: userName
          }, (error: any, result: any) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });

    });
}
```